# 18.04 - after supspend the internal screen shows Dell logo, external screen works (Dell 7285)

Tags: 18.04, graphics, suspend, dell, intel

My Dell 7285 tablet suspends (Suspend-to-RAM, ACPI State:   S3, Label:      "deep") and wakes up and everything works well.

Except: the **internal display only shows the dell logo**.

The external display works and I can login and continue working with the external display.
The internal screen also does not work if no external screen is attached.

The system has a Intel HD Graphics 615 (Kaby Lake GT2) graphics card.
With Windows suspend, wake up works flawlessly.

What can I do to debug this?

Or is there a way to restart the graphics card on resume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I installed Ubuntu 18.10 and it now works.